# Please help me solving this algebraic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was solving a Quantative Aptitude test set and came to this question. I am not getting how to take this equation to the value it is asking for.

Please see:-

if $$ \frac{a}{q-r} = \frac{b}{r-p} = \frac{c}{p-q} $$, find the value of $$ pa+qb+rc ? $$

Options we have:-

1) 0

2) 1

3) 2

4) ­-1

Please explain your answer so that I can trick in similar kind of questions.

Thanks

Comment: Two possible typos: The expression is likely $pa+qb+rc$. Is it? And the option 4 is now the same as option 2.

Comment: Hint: let the common ratio be $\lambda$, so that $a = \lambda(q-r), b=\lambda(r-p), c=\lambda(p-q)\,$. Then $pa+qb+rc = \cdots\;$

Comment: @Bettybel You're right, sorry about my mistake. I've corrected them.

Comment: The general way to solve this kind of questions will probably require quite a bit of studying on your part. Step 1: Write your equations as $P_1=P_2=...P_n=0$ for some polynomials $P_i$. Step 2: Fix a monomial ordering and compute the Groebner basis of the ideal generated by the $P_i$. Step 3: Using the Groebner basis compute the remainder of the division of the polynomial expression which value you are computing by the Groebner basis. The remainder is the value you are looking for.

Comment: @MorganRodgers It is just to address the "similar kind of questions" part.

Comment: @dxiv I would put that as an answer.

Comment: @Bettybel I am getting it difficult to understand, can you explain your theory with solving the above question step by step?

Comment: @SannySrivastava Look, while my comment is meaningful, it is written partly tongue-in-cheek. Maybe it can also motivate some to study about Groebner bases. It would take much more time than needed to solve simpler problems like the one you have using this method.

Comment: @SannySrivastava I changed the question tag to `algebra-precalculus` since it wasn't `linear-algebra` for sure. Also, I don't think Bettybel's comment was meant as a recommendation to follow in the case of this particular problem.

Comment: Perhaps a general moral that is withing grasp is the following. "Division by the Groebner basis" is really elimination of variables. Notice how in dxiv's answer he/she takes the given equations, solves for $a,b,c$ and uses those equations to eliminate $a$, $b$ and $c$ from the expression $pa+qb+rc$. How to eliminate in general takes some work, but a good thing to remember is that eliminating variables is what is going to be involved in the solution of this type of problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: let the common ratio be $\lambda\,$:

$$ \lambda = \frac{a}{q-r} = \frac{b}{r-p} = \frac{c}{p-q} $$

Then $a=\lambda(q−r),b=\lambda(r−p),c=\lambda(p−q)\,$, and:

$$
pa+qb+rc=\lambda\big(p(q-r)+q(r-p)+r(p-q)\big) = \cdots
$$

---

[ *EDIT* ]  For an alternative shortcut:  *given* that this was presented as a multiple choice question, and *assuming* the rules of the game guarantee that one of the choices must be the correct answer, then that answer can only be **a)** $\;=0\,$. This is because of a straightforward homogeneity argument: if $\,a,b,c\,$ were all multiplied by some constant $\,u \ne 0\,$, and $\,p,q,r\,$ were all multiplied by $\,v \ne 0\,$, then the ratios $\,a/(q-r)=b/(r-p)=c/(p-q)\,$ would still be equal, but the sum $\,pa+qb+rc\,$ would get multiplied by $\,u \cdot v\,$. But the only value among $\,\{0,1, 2, -1\}\,$ invariant to scaling is $\,0\,$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but there is something not striking in my mind at the moment, like you said "But the only value among {0,1,2,−1} invariant to scaling is 0". If I take u=v=1, then also the u.v remain same for all ratios. Please explain it to me I guess you are saying something else but I want to understand it correctly.

Comment: @SannySrivastava Point is that it works for $\forall u,v \ne0$. Take $u=v=2$ for example, then $2a / (2q-2r) = a / (q-r) = \lambda$ and the same for the other ratios. But suppose $s=pa+qb+rc$, then $(2p)(2a)+(2q)(2b)+(2r)(2c)=4s$. The only value of $s$ for which $s=4s$ is $s=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Note the property: $$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d} \Rightarrow \frac{a}{b} = \frac{a+c}{b+d}.$$

Multiply the numerator and denominator by $p,q,r$, respectively, and apply the rule above: $$\frac{a}{q-r} = \frac{b}{r-p} = \frac{c}{p-q} \Rightarrow \frac{ap}{pq-pr} = \frac{bq}{qr-qp} = \frac{cr}{r(p-q)} \Rightarrow $$
$$\frac{ap}{pq-pr} = \frac{ap+bq}{r(q-p)} = \frac{cr}{r(p-q)} \Rightarrow$$
$$ap+bq=-cr \Rightarrow ap+bq+cr=0.$$